# Transpose of Directed Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

Can anyone tell me the efficient algorithm to calculate the transpose for Directed Graph for both Adjacency List and Adjacency Matrix Representations? Also, the time complexity of both the algorithms.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have got? Do you have any algorithm in mind?

Comment: This can be as trival as reading the representation backwards, i.e. no processing done at all.

Comment: You might want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499182/3572733

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all edges and reverse their direction. O(V+E) time for adjacency list and O(V^2) time for adjacency matrix.